# ImportError: No module named appengine.api

Tags: python, webapp2

Пытаюсь запустить на ЛОКАЛЬНОЙ машине проект. Скачал все нужные библиотеки, запускаю и мне в ответ:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

Команда:

```
pip install google-appengine
```

не помогает. На  [форуме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848896/google-api-client-python-import-taskqueue) читал, что надо скачать с сайта [GoogleCloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install). Скачал, установил. Сделал все как там было. Все равно ничего не работает.

Может, я что-то пропустил? Кто сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой - как решили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Скачать [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install).
2. Скопировать папку `google` из `C:\Users\ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\python27\sdk\google` в папку виртуального окружения.

Примерный итоговый путь будет таким: `C:\Users\ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ\PycharmProjects\ИМЯ_ПРОЕКТА\venv\Lib\site-packages\google` (ну или если копировать не хочется - тогда в настройках IDE указать путь. Я лично - скопировал)

И питон сразу все нашел. Все подчеркивания исчезли, т.к. `google_appengine` нашелся.